# Is it ok to have two XML tags

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml

So I found an XML file that has someting similar to the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<section>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
</section>
```

Ie. there are two `<?xml>` declarations....Is this a valid XML?...When I tried to load it using PHP's simplexml_load_string, it would return false instead...

Comment: No - http://validator.w3.org/check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-prolog-dtd)

> The document type declaration MUST appear before the first element in the document.

Meaning no that is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

This is invalid due to the rule that the XML declaration must be at the very start of the XML file. The first five characters of an XML document should be `<?xml`.

Answer (score 0):

No, XML-declaration is only allowed at the START of the document.